# How to remap Control and Cmd in Firefox for MacOS?

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, macos-ventura

MacOS allows to assign a hotkey for copy/paste actions via System settings. However [Firefox does not respect remapped application short-cuts in MacOS](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1381952). I tried several external application to remap these actions, and didn't find anything, what would work for this case. At present I have a bit sad experiences, when all applications (even google chrome) use ctrl+c/v for copy/paste, and only firefox refuses to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that karabiner's complex modifications work fine for this case. If someone else also wants to remap ctrl and cmd, you can use this json https://github.com/Hixon10/karabiner-complex-modifications-for-firefox/blob/main/firefox.json